# Persist application disabled across factory reset

Tags: android, android-source

I've been doing some experimentation with Android in order to lock down a kid's phone. Ideally, I'd like him only to be able to use apps that have been pre-installed on the phone; he spends and inordinate amount of time playing games on the phone. I found out that I can disable the Google Play Store on the phone (once rooted) by issuing the command `pm disable com.android.vending`.

However, I suspect that this setting will not persist of the kid factory resets the phone (he knows how to as he's done it before when I locked down his phone with a 3rd party app).

I've managed to get AOSP built and running on the phone and installed the necessary Gapps for Google Fi (our carrier) and other bare essentials, but I want my final Android image to default to com.android.vending being disabled by default unless explicitly re-enabled after, say, a factory reset.

Now, my knowledge of Android is somewhat limited, but from what I have found via some of the `pm` source is that the default enabled/disabled status is specified in the AndroidManifest.xml within the APK package. Since I'm trying to disable a Google app, I likely won't be able to modify this.

So, instead I was attempting to figure out via the pm source how exactly `pm` goes about marking an app as disabled. Unfortunately, my Java comprehensions is terrible so I wasn't able to ascertain anything about the internal workings of how `pm` does this.

Is there any way that I can cause com.vending.android to be disabled in my system root by default when building AOSP?

**Update 1**: It seems that the app disabled status is user-dependent. So, disabling the app for one user does not disable for any others. But, surely, there is a global settings file somewhere that the user configuration inherits from...?

**Update 2**: So, looks like `pm` works with an in-memory state that is not saved (at least for system apps) even upon a reboot.

Answer (score 0):

You should just buy an old phone for your kid. Factory reset will erase everything you have install, including security programs.

Comment: I'm trying to lock down the phone he has, rather than buying a new one. Unless I buy a phone from China that doesn't have the Play Store I would have the same problem with any phone.

Comment: Additionally, as I have gone to the lengths of building a custom Android image for his phone, that means that the "clean slate" factory reset will have whatever apps/settings I have put into the system image as the defaults.

Comment: Ok then add the parent control or any soft that controls google play and use SureLock that prevents factory reset. He won't be able to reset the device or install any more games.. problem solved. Have a look: https://www.42gears.com/blog/how-to-disable-factory-reset-using-surelock/ . Don't forget to check my answer if you find it useful ;)

Comment: My Old Nokia N8 had this feature of a Security App that persisted across factory reset